# YouTube WebUIViewDelegate - respondsToSelector: being sent to the wrong instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube

Here is an excerpt from the `MyYouTube` class where I create a YouTube video:

```
@interface MyYouTube : NSObject <UIWebViewDelegate>
@end

@implementation

- (void) createYouTubeVideoInView: (UIView*) mainView withContent: (NSDictionary*) contentDict {

    // create url request
    NSString * compiledUrl=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://_xxx_.com/app/youtube.php?yt=%@",[contentData objectForKey:@"cnloc"]];
    NSURL * url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:compiledUrl];
    NSURLRequest * request=[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

    // create the web view
    webView=[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRef.bounds];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
    [webView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
    [[webView scrollView] setScrollEnabled:NO];
    [[webView scrollView] setBounces:NO];
    [webView setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction:NO];
    [webView setDelegate:self];

    NSLog(@"YOUTUBE: self: %@",self);
    NSLog(@"YOUTUBE: delegate: %@",webView.delegate);

    // add the webview to the main view
    [mainView addSubview:webView];
}
```

Here's the thing:

If I set the `Delegate` to `nil` then the YouTube video plays fine.

**BUT**

If I set the `Delegate` to `self` then the app crashes and the console shows the following:

```
YOUTUBE: self: <MyYouTube: 0x16e05f70>
YOUTUBE: delegate: <MyYouTube: 0x16e05f70>
*** -[MyYouTube respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x16e2f420
```

Can anyone explain to me why the instances are different?

Why is there a call to `respondsToSelector:` on an instance which is different to the delegate? And how can this be fixed?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is that mainView can be released, causing releasing your webview after exiting from createYouTubeVideoInView method.

Insure that mainView is still alive. Place it on another view before calling this method.

And insure that you are having strong reference on MyYouTube object(NSObject). Make it an instance variable, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The MyYouTube object definitely has a strong reference. As for the `mainView` - Ive got a UIView with a strong reference declared in my AppDelegate, and I am passing this to the MyYouTube object as a parameter, which ends up as `mainView`. Is this correct? Is there a better way of passing a reference to this UIView?

Comment: seems correct..try to investigate putting a break in - dealloc() method inside MyYouTube object? What if it's being deallocated unexectedly?

Comment: Thanks @alex, you lead me towards the answer I needed. What I needed to do was set the delegate of the webview to nil from inside the dealloc() method.